# How to exclude specified characters from a line?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm filtering a text file with numbers and names I have these commands

```
sed -En 'h;:a;s/^(.)\1+//;ta;/^$/{x;p}'
```

I tried to edit this command and searched how to but i haven't get the required result.

How to exclude the first or the second character in a line from being consecutive duplicates? 
If I have the input like:

```
1122
133555
1366622
256651155
311144
```

The output should be:

```
133555 (only the first character is not consecutively repeated)
1366622 (only the first and the second characters are not consecutively repeated).
311144 (only the first or the second character is not consecutively repeated)
```

The above command is to print only the lines with all consecutively duplicates two or more times.

Comment: Hello Theo could you please edit that command for me ?

Comment: Sorry, no. I just added the `regex` tag for you so you are geting a better chance that other people who know the sed syntax can help you with the regular expression.

Comment: Ok ... Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what the sentence "How to exclude the first or the second character in a line from being consecutive duplicates?" means. It's not clear after reading your example, either.

Comment: Dear Haken Lid my above command prints only the lines with all consecutively repeated characters i want to print only the lines that with all consecutively repeated characters except the first or the second character from being consecutive duplicated. NON CONSECUTIVELY REPEATED CHARACTERS ARE ALLOWED ONLY AT THE FIRST OR THE SECOND CHARACTER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you are going for, but this will give you the expected results for your sample data.

```
sed -nE '/^(.)\1/!{/^(.|..)((.)\3+)+$/p}'
```

Explanation

```
/^(.)\1/  # matches lines starting with two identical characters
!{...}    # run this block when the preceding pattern does not match
/^(.|..)((.)\3+)+$/p   # consecutive duplicates (but first/second char doesn't have to belong to sequence
```

Comment: Thanks Håken Lid its ok.

Comment: Use comments for clarifications and suggestions. If you think an answer is helpful or unhelpful, give an upvote or downvote. If it solves your problem, you can mark the answer as accepted.